# Django. Specific error handling, without including try-catch in every calling function

Tags: django, exception

In Django, can I specify that a specific error should always be handled in a particular way? Specifically, I want the page to redirect to another url.

```
class MyOwnError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

def function_2():
    raise MyOwnError()

def handle_my_own_error(request)
    do stuff
    return HttpResponseRedirect("some_path") 

def calling_function(request):
    function_2()
    # I want to redirect to the result of handle_my_own_error(), without having to specify try-exception here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If error handling is supposed to happen in a view (which I assume due usage of redirect)

You can write custom middleware that process custom exception. See more in django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception